# SQL: length of full name

Tags: sql, database, command, output

I got a task in which I should have the length of the full name of an employee output, but I don't know how to output the length of two columns.

The task:

> 

Enter the personal number, first and last name and the total length of their name for all employees. The sorting should be done according to the total length of the name.

> 

the length should be displayed without spaces between the first and last name

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show what you have so far. And what DB engine do you use?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   Select *, len(firstname||lastname) tot_length from table
   Order by tot_length
```